# Background suspend fire and forget channel processing in Kotlin + Spring

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What is the correct way to rake Channel in the background?

Suppose I have long polling bot with `onMessage(callbackSuspendAction: suspend.() -> Unit)` and this callback is a heavy computation (20-30 seconds)

I put these events to the `messageHandlersQueue: Channel<Job>`
in the following way:

```
messageHandlersQueue.send(
    coroutineScope {
        launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
            val vkClient = VkClient(actor.userActor)
            processVkUserQuery(msg.chat.id, addressName, vkClient)
        }
    }
)
```

I want to have the background raking process, like

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    repeat(5) {
        launch {
            setupMessageHandlerConsumer()
        }
    }
}
```

using the Spring lifecycle.

I need something similar to @Scheduled, but with fixedDelay = 0 or @PostConstruct with suspend signature, where I can put my fire and forget channel raking coroutine process

I am also interested in the best pure spring-java solution (without kafka & kotlin) of multiple producers multiple consumers problem (blocking queue raking in the background without fixedDelay).

**UPD:** didn't come up with a channel solution so far (where to effectively place N running suspend consumers in Spring?). Replaced Channel -> BlockingQueue, suspend handlers -> executor service, like this:

Adding to the blocking queue in onMessage:

```
WAITING_SEARCH_INPUT -> {
    if (validateAddressLink(text)) {
        val addressName = extractAddressName(text)
        val offered = searchQueries.offer(VkUserQuery(chatId, addressName, session.client))
        if (!offered) {
            bot.sendMessage(chatId, TOO_MUCH_LOAD_MESSAGE)
        }
    } else {
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, WRONG_ADDRESS_NAME_FORMAT_MESSAGE)
    }
}
```

Raking:

```
private fun setupSearchQueriesProcessor() {
    for (i in 0 until RAKING_THREADS_COUNT) {
        executorService.submit {
            searchQueryConsumer()
        }
    }
}

private fun searchQueryConsumer() {
    while (true) {
        val searchQuery = searchQueries.take()
        vkSessionRegistry.setState(searchQuery.chatId, SEARCHING)
        processVkUserQuery(
            searchQuery.chatId,
            searchQuery.addressName,
            searchQuery.client
        )
        vkSessionRegistry.setState(searchQuery.chatId, RESTING)
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is unclear to me. Is this `messageHandlersQueue.send()` inside the `onMessage` callback? Why wouldn't you just send the events (some data) to the channel instead of `Job`s? It seems like the wrong thing to transfer. Also, what is the problem with the long running computation if the callback is `suspend` anyway?

Comment: Note that the `coroutineScope { ... }` block waits for all child coroutines to finish. This is very likely not what you want here, since all the enqueued jobs will already be completed on the spot before being sent to the queue.

Comment: I want to control the load, like only N running jobs in the moment

Comment: So why not send just the event/input data through the channel, and then spawn N coroutines to actually do the work on the other side? Here it seems you're trying to launch lazy coroutines immediately, and then the N actors would just `join()` them. It doesn't really express the intent IMO

Comment: thank you for your answers! putting input data is certainly better, but the question is where is the best place to spawn in Spring these N actors processing the inputs, I need something like @Scheduled with fixedDelayed = 0

Comment: Oh I didn't realize the question was specifically about this part. I just got distracted by the non-working enqueuing code. I don't have a definite answer for this, but I would say it might make sense to spawn those actors wherever you start the thing that produces those events. If you can reduce the lifetime/scope of those actor coroutines, I think it'd be nicer than global forever-running coroutines. I'm sorry if this is a bit vague :D